# Firebase Rules with facebook Authentication and Unique IDs

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm looking for some advice or a possible solution with tightening up my firebase rules.

This is my user tree in Firebase:

```
users
    |_male
         |_uid

    |_female
         |_uid
```

The UID will be an epoch timestamp when the account is created which will be a signed integer.

These are the firebase rules which basically ensures the user has logged in and authenticated with Facebook before they can read or write to users:

```
"users": {
       "male":{
          ".indexOn": ["uid"]
       },
       "female":{
         ".indexOn": ["uid"]
       },
       ".read": "auth != null  && auth.provider === 'facebook'",
       ".write": "auth != null && auth.provider === 'facebook'"
},
```

I only want users to read/write to their tree, for example:

```
users->male->uid->1233254...
```

I'm afraid with my rules above, they could potentially read and write from/to another users tree.

It would be great if I could compare the app UID with the Facebook UID.
I do capture this detail in another tree on the database e.g:

```
user_fbuid
         |_fbuid
               |_facebook:a1244dxs
                                 |_uid
```

I do have better rules here that check against `auth.uid`:

```
"user_fbuid": {
      "fbuid":{
        "$fbuid": {
          ".indexOn": ["fbuid"],
          ".read": "$fbuid === auth.uid && auth.provider === 'facebook'",
          ".write": "$fbuid === auth.uid && auth.provider === 'facebook'"
       }
   },
},
```

If anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the facebook id attribute as my own uid and the rules below:

```
"$uid": {
          // only the user can read and write to their tree
          ".read": "auth != null  && auth.provider === 'facebook' && auth.token.firebase.identities['facebook.com'][0] === $uid",
            ".write": "auth != null  && auth.provider === 'facebook' && auth.token.firebase.identities['facebook.com'][0] === $uid"
        },
```