# Can i use firestore security rules if i am using facebook login and i get Facebook profile id as document id?

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase-security

For example
My firestore **collection** name is "college"

**document** name is
"That users Facebook_profile_id"

**feild** is "swimming=true"

How can i restrict this user from updating swimming as false.

Comment: You'll want to log the ID token that Firebase creates, as everything that is in there ends up in `auth.request.token` as far as I know. See for example this for how to look up the identity-specific values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47719425